# The data still there after PV/PVC deleted in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a single pod postgres deployment on my local machine, I use PVC / PV for the data store.

At beginning I started postgres in v15, and later I changed to v14, but it complains: `The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 15, which is not compatible with this version 14.6.` even after I delete everything and start again. Do you guys know what's going on?

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:14-alpine
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pvc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 300Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2
```

Comment: You use a `hostPath` volume and use the same directory.

Comment: How can we delete the data when delete the pv?

Comment: The same way you delete files on your OS from other directories, perhaps?

Comment: Emm, could not locate the PV directory on my macbook, do you know where it is? By the way, I am using kind.

Comment: @Ron you are using the hostpath as a source for PV. So, you can find the directory in the node in which the PV was created. You can login into the node and find the hostpath and clear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My context is using `kind` on macbook.

The PV is physically on the `kind` container. After delete the PV, we need to manually delete the folder. The following command will delete the physical folder.

```
docker exec -it $(docker ps -a | grep kind-control-plane | awk '{print $1}')  rm -rf /your-hostpath
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do you guys know what's going on?

You are using [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) volume, so you are just using a local directory on your local machine. And there seem to be some files in this directory.

When using PersistentVolumeClaims in a cloud environment, it is common to use volumes that are provisioned from a cloud system, where you get a new volume for each PVC.

Comment: I am using `kind`, It seems data will not be deleted even the PV is deleted.

Comment: This is not related to `PV` but to the _directory with files on the host_ since you used a `hostPath` PV.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with retain policy as Recycle, working for me.

> persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle

In case of Recycle the data within the host folder is deleted completely.

> Eg: rm -rf /mnt/data/*

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaim-policy